# Compare two lists and Identify string position where difference occurs

Tags: python

I'm trying to compile two like-lists, but keep the difference between them mitigated to individual strings.

In the example below, I have two lists: one with grouped words `lst_a`, and one without `lst_b`.

One list `lst_b` is also shorting in length.

I want to give `lst_b` the groupings of `lst_a`, but when a difference between the two lists occurs, I would like only to have one stings that is different in `lst_b`

**Here is my attempt:**

```
# my two original lists
lst_a = ['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver red', 'white orange brown']
lst_b = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'gold', 'silver', 'white', 'orange', 'brown']

# my lists for determining the number of words in each string 
number_a = []
number_b = []

# my lists to help create new_lst_b
new_lst_b = []
index = 0

# how many strings are in lst_a
for item in lst_a:
    number_a.append(len(item.split()))

# take the number of strings in lst_a and apply create new_lst_b with the same number of stings
for i in number_a:
    new_lst_b.append(' '.join(lst_b[index:(index + i)]))
    index += i

# how many strings are in new_lst_b
for item_b in new_lst_b:
    number_b.append(len(item_b.split()))

# print the position of each string in lst_a and new_lst_b
lst_a_pos = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(lst_a)]
lst_b_pos = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(new_lst_b)]

# Finding the difference between lst_a_pos and lst_b_pos
def Diff_lst(lst_a_pos, lst_b_pos):
    return list(set(lst_a_pos) - set(lst_b_pos))
diff_lst_b = Diff_lst(lst_b_pos, lst_a_pos)

# Sorting the results of diff_lst_b without including the position
diff_lst_b_sorted = sorted(diff_lst_b, key = lambda x: int(x.split(', ')[0]))

print(new_lst_b)
print(diff_lst_b_sorted)
print(number_a)
print(number_b)
```

**Here is the output:**

```
['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver white', 'orange brown']
['2, silver white', '3, orange brown']
[3, 4, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 2, 2]
```

**Here is what I would like to have as the desired output:**

```
final_lst_b =  ['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver', ' white orange brown']
```

What I'm trying to do is find the string where the difference between the two lists begins, and calculate how many words in the `new_lst_b` string are difference from the `lst_a` string.

I tried to calculate the difference between the two strings with the code below, but it fails.

```
def Diff_item(lst_a[2], new_lst_b[2]):
    return list(set(lst_a[2]) - set(new_lst_b[2]))
diff_item_b = Diff_lst(new_lst_b[2], lst_a[2])
```

My thinking was maybe I could recalculate `lst_b` with a `new_number_b` which would read `[3, 4, 1, 3]`

Regardless, any help/direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: For sure, sorry I was confusing. Basically, I want to know what value in `new_number_b` I need to adjust, and by how much. I want to calculate this by finding which string the difference began, and by how many letters.

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me, nor are your requirements. Are you just trying to get the ouput in `final_lst_b`? Does the *order* matter?

Comment: My apologies! Yes the I would like to get the output in `final_lst_b`, and the order does matter.

Comment: I mean, for the difference. Do you basically start at the position in list b where the first color is, then throw out any  in the string in list a that doesn't align with the order in list b?

Comment: For example, for `'yellow green pink gold'`, if list b had `[..., 'yellow', 'pink', 'black', 'green', 'gold', ...]` what would the output for that part be?

Comment: Or phrased another way, do you just stop after the first mismatch, regardless of what comes after? Like, for the above, you would only have `'yellow'`?

Comment: Assuming the `new_lst_b[0]` string was left alone, the output for `print(diff_lst_b_sorted)` would be '['1, yellow pink black green gold', '2, silver white', '3, orange brown']

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking, dude. I'm asking about *the final result*.

Comment: Again, my apologies. So for the final result whatever order the colors are in for lst_a, final_lst_b needs to mirror that order.

Comment: **so what would it be?** Just `'yellow'`? Take a step back and try to explain *what you are trying to accomplish*, not in terms of *how you are trying to accomplish it now*. Because "I want to give lst_b the groupings of lst_a, but when a difference between the two lists occurs, I would like only to have one stings that is different in lst_b" doesn't make sense

Comment: So for this example yes, I would only want lst_b[1] to contain 'yellow', but I would not want lst_b[2] to read 'pink black', and subsequently lst_b[3] to read 'green gold red' and so on.

Comment: Basically, for the problem I am working on, there will not be any colors that exist in lst_b that do not exist in lst_a. There will only be deletions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# my two original lists
lst_a = ['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver red', 'white orange brown']
lst_b = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'gold', 'silver', 'white', 'orange', 'brown']

#create a new_list of same length as lst_a
new_list = ['']*len(lst_a)

#split the words in lst_a so you can access each word separately
a = [_.split(' ') for _ in lst_a]

#check each word against lst_b and if it is present, form the new list
for i, l in enumerate(a):
    new_list[i] = ' '.join([j for j in l if j in lst_b])

#finally print the new list that contains only items in lst_b
print(new_list)
```

Output for the above code is:

```
['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver', 'white orange brown']
```

Let me know if this works for you. If you need help with any of this, let me know. Thanks for posting the question. It was fun writing the code for this.

The below code (full set) maybe what you are looking for. There may be options for you to optimize. I didn't spend enough time to look for them. However, it does provide you what you want.

```
# my two original lists
lst_a = ['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver red', 'white orange brown']
lst_b = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'temp', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'gold', 'silver', 'white', 'orange', 'brown']
#note: I added 'temp' as a new color to the list

#create a new_list of same length as lst_a
new_list = ['']*len(lst_a)

#split the words in lst_a so you can access each word separately
a = [_.split(' ') for _ in lst_a]

#check each word against lst_b and if it is present, form the new list
for i, l in enumerate(a):
    new_list[i] = ' '.join([j for j in l if j in lst_b])

#this section is the addition to find the missing color from lst_b
#convert all the colors in lst_a into single items so you can scan against lst_b
s = [j for i in a for j in i]
#remove any duplicate colors from lst_a
#Easier to process the smaller list
s = list(dict.fromkeys(s))

#now create a list of all items that are in lst_b but not in lst_a
temp = [x for x in lst_b if x not in s]

#now add list temp to new_list to create the full list

new_list += temp

#finally print the new list that contains only items in lst_b
print(new_list)
```

Output for the new list:
the missing colors will show up at the end. Hope this is what you want.

```
['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver', 'white orange brown', 'temp']
```

An alternate way to implement missing items from lst_b:

```
#now create a list of all items that are in lst_b but not in lst_a
temp = [x for x in lst_b if x not in s]
```

Replace this with:

```
temp = list(set(lst_b) - set(s))
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again! Would there also be a way to say "If a word exists in `lst_b` but not in `lst_a`, include it in `new_lst`?

Comment: @teddygraham, yes, anything is possible in programming. Do you want to give it a try? It will be similar to the for i, l in enumerate(a) implementation. you may have to do some tweaks to get the result. I will post the updated code when I am back on my laptop

Comment: No problem at all, thank you for all the help! That would be great, I would like to try making it work if possible!

Comment: @teddygraham, I provided new code for you to try. See if this works.

Comment: This is great, thank you! However, I do have one more question: is it possible to have the output: `['black blue purple', 'temp yellow green pink gold', 'silver', 'white orange brown']`?

Comment: How do you determine it is not 'black blue purple temp' versus 'temp yellow green pink gold'.  Mind you 'temp' can be part of either. Also, will there be another set of colors that may have temp? for example 'silver red temp' In that case, temp exists in lst_a so if i add 'temp yellow green pink' then it may be incorrect. Let me know so we can figure out the best way to implement it.

Comment: I see, that is a good point. I think that the original lists would actually read: lst_a = ['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver red', 'white orange brown']
lst_b = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'temp', 'green', 'pink', 'gold', 'silver', 'white', 'orange', 'brown']. Where `temp` is actually replacing `yellow` in lst_b. So it may be easier to determine what string `temp` belongs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219064/discussion-between-joe-ferndz-and-teddygraham).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, because there are a lot of unstated assumptions/specifications. You need to take a step back from your implementation and *try to explain what you are trying to accomplish in a precise way*. In any case, I *believe* you are after something like this:

```
lst_a = ['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver red', 'white orange brown']
lst_b = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'gold', 'silver', 'white', 'orange', 'brown']

# create an index from color to index so to improve efficiency
index = {color:i for i, color in enumerate(lst_b)}


result = []
for string in lst_a:
    temp = []
    colors = string.split()
    start_index = index[colors[0]]
    for color, i in zip(colors, range(start_index, len(lst_b))):
        if lst_b[i] == color:
            temp.append(color)
        else: # stop accumulating matches at first difference
            break
    result.append(' '.join(temp))

print(result)
```

This gives:

```
['black blue purple', 'yellow green pink gold', 'silver', 'white orange brown']
```